# Is there a source for historical shapefiles and tiles? 

Tags: data

Is there a source for historical shapefiles and tiles? Like the ancient Greece/Rome, medieval Europe and Japan? Ideally with multiple snapshots during different periods in their development, since they've gone through quite a bit of restructuring over their lifespans.

Comment: sorry they didn't have shape files back then. :)

Comment: but we do now, and we have maps from back then... I was actually very surprised that my google search revealed nothing useful in this regard.

Comment: My guess would be that most of the effort (=money) being spent is in the research area, which has traditionally utilized raster analysis (probably grass).  And so not much effort spent converting the data to vector.

Comment: is the tiles in your title referring to raster tiles or are you just interested in historic data as shape file and/or raster images?

Comment: @BradNesom both, the rasters would be nice for visual, but shapefiles are technically all I need.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a couple ideas:

Japan: http://www.fas.harvard.edu/~chgis/japan/

Ancient World: http://pleiades.stoa.org/

Comment: You tagged a five year old answer for this? lol

Answer (score 7):

take a look at:
http://nils.weidmann.ws/projects/cshapes

Quote from the website:
"CShapes is a new dataset that provides historical maps of state boundaries and capitals in the post-World War II period. The dataset is coded according to both the Correlates of War and the Gleditsch and Ward (1999) state lists, and is therefore compatible with a great number of existing databases in the discipline. Provided in a geographic data format, CShapes can be used directly with standard GIS software, allowing a wide range of spatial computations. In addition, we supply a CShapes package for the R statistical toolkit. This package enables researchers without GIS skills to perform various useful operations on the GIS maps"

**Update:** Version2 of Cshapes can be found here:
https://icr.ethz.ch/data/cshapes/

Comment: This link is dead, thus not working nowadays.

Comment: @Trikelians added new link for new version2 of cshapes

Answer (score 5):

Here’s something for the US.

The National Historical Geographic Information System (NHGIS) provides, free of charge, aggregate census data and GIS-compatible boundary files for the United States between 1790 and 2010.

https://www.nhgis.org

Answer (score 4):

Great Britain has http://visionofbritain.org.uk/

Using Scanned Maps that have been georeferenced and combined with historical elements, census, election results and more.

**Example - Ordnance Survey Unions 1803**

http://visionofbritain.org.uk/iipmooviewer/iipmooviewer.html?fileName=os_unions_1803_1838_se%2FIndex_1803_1838%3DUncredited%3DOrdnance+Survey%3DUnions%3DIndex&x=27&y=91

more info on the project:
http://visionofbritain.org.uk/index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a link for data but this use case is extremely interesting.

coincidental post on another site.
Q: Just for the sake of curiosity Tom, what type of projects are you doing with such a powerful machine?

> A: "Glad you asked. The primary use is in attempting to locate the
>   precise camera location of a set of exposures taken somewhere on the
>   Gettysburg battlefield one day after the battle.   The ArcObject
>   program I wrote attempts to do this by matching the 2 dimensional
>   horizon visible in one of the exposures with that visible from every
>   10' x 10' location on the historical battlefield.   Rays are projected
>   toward the horizon at every 4 degree increment.   Using a sort
>   algorithm the inclination and distance to the horizon is determined.
>   From this a 2-D horizon is calculated and match attempted...   The
>   result is 90 10'x10' rasters with a value that reflects the likelyhood
>   of matching. A total run takes just 30 days using all the processors. 
>   There is also a spatial model that uses 1863 Shapefile to reflect
>   other elements visible in the exposures (water, slope, ground cover,
>   etc.).   This model produces 90 additional raster that are combined
>   with the first set...  Ultimately producing suggested camera locations
>   and viewing directions; which require field trips to evaluate and
>   update the models... "

[Linkedin Group](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=86844&trk=myg_ugrp_ovr)
Re-post from a linkedin group. Now that is digging into history!