# Where can I find historic country border data?

Tags: data, borders

I am looking for border polygons from World War I (from 1914-1918). Is there a resource out there that maintains this kind of information?

Comment: Please provide more detail.  What area of the world?  I imagine that borders in Europe or Africa or Asia may be available, but from different sources.  Also, I think you are likely to find paper maps that could be digitized as a good starting point.

Comment: @GetSpatial Country borders for Europe and the surrounding region would be very useful. In the context of the first World War.

Comment: can you use rastermaps too or do you need to use vector-maps only?

Comment: @kurt Vector would definitely be preferable

Answer (score 6):

This may be what you're looking for:

http://library.thinkquest.org/C006628/GIS.html

Comment: Disclaimer can be found here:  http://library.thinkquest.org/C006628/GIS.html

Comment: This may also be useful:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17137/is-there-a-source-for-historical-shapefiles-and-tiles/17271#17271

Comment: thanks for the link. This is an excellent resource for more than just 1914. It has a wide range shape files across many centuries. These do, however, seem rather rough as though hand drawn. Best option so far but perhaps there are more accurate ones out there?

Answer (score 3):

euroatlas has detailled shapefiles for europe 1900, unfortunately not free, but there is a free sample, so that you can check the quality of the data. infos and download of sample: http://shop.euratlas.com/maps_gis/gis_1900.html

the IEG-maps offer good raster-maps free for personal use: e.g. europe 1914 http://www.ieg-maps.uni-mainz.de/mapsp/mappEu914Serie1.htm and http://www.ieg-maps.uni-mainz.de/mapsp/mappEu914Serie2.htm. there are also more detailled maps for diffferent parts of europe, e.g. central-europe 1914 http://www.ieg-maps.uni-mainz.de/mapsp/map914ME.htm