# How to create vector-based maps showing historic borders

Tags: map-drawing, history

I'm an absolute beginner in map making.

I want to create digital maps with European historic borders that all have the same projection and style. All the data should be vectorized.

My idea is to have a blank digital map on which I draw the borders. To create the borders I take an existing map that shows the historic borders.

My questions:

- Is there a collection of hgis data (freely) available so that I don't have to do it myself?
- Is there a good tutorial for my task?
- How do I map the map showing historic borders to the blank map?
- How do I copy the border map? Should I use a tablet an pin a print of the map on it?

Comment: My guess as to why this question has receieved so many close-votes is that there are actually 5 or more questions here, none of which are very clear. The Q&A format of this site works best with singular, focused questions. The only question that this site can really help you with is "where can I find historic border data", which has been asked here before [multiple](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/32943/753) [times](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/17137/753).

Comment: Would be helpful if people would comment their reason for closing the question