# Seeking public database to input date and city to determine country at time and present-day?

Tags: data, geonames, gazetteer

I'm looking to automate a common task for us.  For example, Jaromir Jagr was born in Kladno in 1972.  I want to be able to take that and output a string.

Born in Kladno, Czechoslovakia (present-day Czech Republic).

I'm a little bit familiar with geonames.org, but I'm not sure if it has the historical component.  Any places that have that?

Comment: Only for NHL hockey players or any city in the world/ any country.   Some cities have split and merged, been renamed, villages have disappear to natural disasters, surface mining and war, etc, country borders changes many times in recent history...It can get real complex, real fast.  Interesting though.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32943 and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17137 may help

Comment: @Jakub  Any city.  I realize some may not be easily managed, but just wondering if there is a resource available.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any such public database but I suspect the term for what you are seeking is an historical gazetteer.

Since you are looking for a public database, I think this is a question which could be posted at, and perhaps attract more interest on, the [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  What are the private/for-pay sources that might have this?

Comment: I am not aware of any private/for-pay sources but, if they exist, then a way to uncover them may be to ask at [opendata.se] if this is available as open data and see if anyone says "not as open data, but it can be obtained from ...".