# Where can I find world map shapefiles/GEOJSONs/KMLs for 1950-2015?

Tags: shapefile, data, geojson, kml

I'm looking for world maps showing countries from 1950-2015. Are there shapefiles, KMLs or GEOJSON files of these?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a source for historical shapefiles and tiles?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17137/is-there-a-source-for-historical-shapefiles-and-tiles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have a look at [cshapes](http://nils.weidmann.ws/projects/cshapes) it...

> "provides historical maps of state boundaries and capitals in the
>   post-World War II period".

You can download a shapefile and query the data using the fields containing the year to evaluate how country shapes have changed over time. I found this website by first looking on the [PennLibraries website](http://guides.library.upenn.edu/globalgis).